# How to convert "SEL" and "id" to NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, selector

```
id parent;
SEL selector;

// lot's of code...

if ([parent respondsToSelector:selector]) {

}
else {
    // This doesn't work:
    NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ in class %@ doesn't exist!", selector, parent];
}
```

How do I convert "SEL" and "id" to a String?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Call [`NSStringFromSelector()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromSelector) passing your selector as its argument to get the selector string, and use `[parent class]` for the `parent` object's class:

```
NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ in class %@ doesn't exist!",
    NSStringFromSelector(selector), 
    [parent class]];
```

Comment: The opposite way is:
SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"tapMeAction:");

Comment: just wanted to point out that "@%s",_cmd use to work (and still does) but now post a warning.  this seems to be the proper way

Comment: Note - the format of the string returned by `NSStringFromSelector` is simply the selector, e.g. `@"setTitle:"`. i.e. it has no `@selector(~)` wrapping etc.